# Importing a 1024bit key into SF

Tags: integration, xml, api-client-certificate

we are integrating into a government system (yep one of those!)
they have given us a PFX certificate and I have managed to use openssl and java keystore to convert it to a JKS file

When I tried to import it into SF however I get the following error:

> Error: The 1,024 bit key size used for "signedcert" is unacceptable.

I raised a case with SF hoping that they could maybe enable 1024 bit keys (because ofcourse SF used to support that in the past) but got a definite NO on that.

Any suggestions on how we can integrate these synchronous outbound REST XML interfaces using the 1024bit key we have been given? Perhaps some app or heroku app, etc?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the key? _Synchronous outbound REST XML_ is broad.

Comment: trying to import a certificate so that I can connect to an external system using HTTP

Comment: HTTP does not require a certificate.

Comment: https protocol to connect